# Issue when using DataTable.Select(somestring) versus DataTable.AsEnumerable().Where

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, ienumerable

I am trying to convert an old code which is preparing a where clause first and call select on DataTable, to a chaining method using AsEnumerable(). But my code does not produce the same result. Any insight would be appreciated .

#### Old Code - which is creating a where clause to find the result

```
        bool OLD_Method()
        {
            GetNames(inputparam, out DataSet names);
        
            string find = "Name IN ('ABC', 'BCD') AND IsTrue = 1 ";
            DataRow[] foundRows = names.Tables[0].Select(find);
        
            if (foundRows.Any()) return true;
            return false;
        }
```

---

#### New Code which accepts array of strings and uses chaining method

```
        bool NEW_Method(string[] params) //NEW_Method(new string[]{'ABC', 'BCD'})
        {
            GetNames(inputparam, out DataSet names);
        
            var foundRows =  names?.Tables[0]?.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(myRow => params.Any(p => myRow.Field<string>("Name").Equals(p)) 
                       && myRow.Field<int>("IsTrue") == 1
                 );
        
            if (foundRows.Any()) return true;
            return false;
        }
```

---

**Update - 1** - Above works, if I were to just use one item, but with multiple it is failing. I thought usage of Any() should act as an OR, but maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The old code could be performing a case-insensitive comparison whereas the new method is case sensitive.

There is actually a property on the DataTable that determines whether the Select will be case-sensitive or not.

You can amend your second query to be the same as the first as follows.

```
StringComparison sc = (names?.Tables[0]?.CaseSensitive?? false) 
    ? StringComparison.CurrentCulture 
    : StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;

 var foundRows =  names?.Tables[0]?.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(myRow => params.Any(p => String.Equals(myRow.Field<string>("Name") , p, sc )
               && myRow.Field<int>("IsTrue") == 1
         ));
```

Comment: Thank you, so my code is right ? but it is the case sensitivity?

Comment: I must be missing something else too, as I just verified that I am using exact case sensitive  strings

Comment: @VivekShukla I am not sure what you mean by 'case sensitive strings'. But I have added an example of how you can amend the new method to give you the same results as the old code.